# How to record a user text selection on a web page and track the selected text for future changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications, web-crawler

For my application, I need to be able to record user selected text on a web page, and then revisit the web page with a web crawler and see if the text that the user highlighted has changed at a future time. The text that I'm tracking is product information.

Getting the text that the user has selected is easy enough with JavaScript, but getting a reliable way of recording where in the document a crawler should visit to check the information isn't.

One of the main problems is that the JavaScript Dom representation of the document is not the same as the raw html. I have tried creating regular expressions based on the text surrounding the user selected text, but for this reason this is unreliable.

XPath is another option, but is likely to suffer the same problems.

If anyone could suggest a technique I could use here, it would be very very much appreciated.

Comment: The user can highlight any part or portion of any piece of content on the page? Tracking that sounds pretty much impossible. This *may* have a chance to work if you let the user specify DOM elements, but even then it's going to be awfully tough. Maybe somebody else comes up with a genius idea that I'm not thinking of, but I can't see it.

Comment: sounds like screen scraping. We did this at a a very famous british aggregation website (think supermarket) way back when. The genius bit was having upwards of 100 developers dedicated to writing scripts to extract product information.  It can be done if the desire is there. But is highly costly!! Try and get a feed, might need critical mass first though...lol

Comment: Why not simply sending AJAX request whenever user makes a selection and recording this into some log? What do you need crawler for??

Comment: @brumScouse - Thanks for the insight there. Good to hear that this is not a trivial problem I've got here.